# gradient property in img tag

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to gradient my image but it never shows

```css
.asdf img  {
 background: rgb(2,0,36);
background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(9,9,121,1) 35%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
            }
```

```html
<div class="asdf text-center tx-white">

  <img style="height: 200px;" class="w-100 shadow-sm bd" src="{{url($xd->banner)}}"alt="">

</div>
```

what is the correct way to show the gradient on the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it as background-image, not as img.

```css
.asdf img {
object-fit: cover;
}

.asdf .img { background-image:
    linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(245, 246, 252, 0.52), rgba(117, 19, 93, 0.73)),
 url('https://cdn.the-scientist.com/assets/articleNo/66864/aImg/35078/foresttb-l.jpg');
 width: 80%;
    height: 500px;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="asdf text-center tx-white">

    <div class="w-100 shadow-sm bd img" ></div>
  
  </div>
```

updated, linear-gradient with img tag:

```css
img {
 max-width: 100%;
  }
  
  .hero-image {
 max-width: 100%; 
 width: 800px;
 margin: auto;
  }
  
  .hero-image::after {
 display: block;
 position: relative;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0, #fff 100%);
 margin-top: -150px;
 height: 150px;
 width: 100%;
 content: '';
  }
```

```html
 <div class="hero-image">
    <img src='https://cdn.the-scientist.com/assets/articleNo/66864/aImg/35078/foresttb-l.jpg' />
  </div>
```

Comment: there is no way to apply the gradient to the image with img? is that if I remove <img> I can't get the image dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You have to set width and height property on img's parent (div), to extend image size and cover it with background. Or do it with image.